# GreenSock GSAP: Multiple eases for different attributes?

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I have an element animating from the top-left corner to the center of the screen:

```
TweenMax.to($("#char"), 1, {top: "50%", left:"50%", ease:Power1.easeOut});
```

This animates in a straight line, with some easing. What I want is a more circular animation that follows this path:

[image: Circular animation]

so I have to use multiple TweenMax.to() calls, with different easing on each one:

```
TweenMax.to($("#char"), 1, {top: "50%", ease:Circ.easeIn});
TweenMax.to($("#char"), 1, {left:"50%", ease:Circ.easeOut});
```

Is there a way to assign a different ease for each attribute in a single `TweenMax.to()` call? Something like this, perhaps?

```
TweenMax.to($("#char"), 1, [{top: "50%", ease:Circ.easeIn}, {left:"50%", ease:Circ.easeOut}]);
```

I've looked all over their docs, and it seems that I can only pass one ease that will apply to all attributes.

Comment: There isn't any way of doing that. I'd think because another line of code doesn't hurt. You can, however, dig into the source and handle the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think multiple eases is what you should be looking for if you want to achieve curviness.

There is a [BezierPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/BezierPlugin/) which, IMHO, should help you create a curved path. Take a look at an overly simplified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/7cpqzz3w/) I created. The code of which as follows:

```
var div=document.querySelector('div');
TweenMax.fromTo(div, 2, {position: 'absolute', top: '0%', left: '0%'}, {bezier: {type: 'soft', values: [{top: '0%', left: '50%'}, {top: '50%', left: '50%'}], autoRotate: true}, ease: Power2.easeInOut});
```

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know about the Bezier plugin.